# Check default mail client using C# code

Tags: c#

How to find default mail client using C#? i checked some posted here but it didn't help me..

I used this code

```
object mailClient = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail", "", "none");
```

In my computer both windows live mail and outlook installed and the defualt client is windows live mail however if i print mailclient it will show defualt mail client as outlook.

but if i use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:")` then it will open in windows live mail which is correct.

i need a method to find defualt client through C# code.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry keys are:

**Machine:**
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command`

**User:**
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command`

The values for these keys are the command-lines that get executed, and they contain a `%1` for the address after the `mailto:`.  Because of that, you'll probably have to do some additional parsing to get just the path to the executable:

**Example:**
`"C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" -c IPM.Note /m "%1"` would need to just become `"C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"`.

Answer (score 0):

To open a message with the "To" already filled, try

```
string target = "joe.doe@doecontry.dc";

string mailtoCommand =
    (string) Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command", @"", @"none");
mailtoCommand = mailtoCommand.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Replace("%1", target);

string arguments =
    mailtoCommand.Substring(mailtoCommand.ToLower().IndexOf(@".exe", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 4);

string fileName = mailtoCommand.Substring(0, mailtoCommand.Length - arguments.Length);

Process.Start(fileName, arguments);
```