# How to check whats the default mail client is installed on Windows System?

Tags: c#, wpf, email, outlook

I am developing an application for Windows 7/8/8.1 in C# WPF, for this I need to know what the systems default mail client is.

I searched Stackoverflow and Google, what I found was

```
RegistryKey hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey mailClients = hklm.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Clients\\Mail");
string defaultClient = (string)mailClients.GetValue("");
   if (defaultClient == null)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Error");
       return;
   }

   else
       Process.Start("mailto: " + "?subject=" + SomeSubject + "&body=" + Body);
```

But in a few cases seen that this is not a optimal solution to check for the default mail client in a Windows system. For example, I have one system where `OutLook 2010` is installed and I receive an error when I try to open the `outlook email` window,  `"The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using".` Is there any perfect way to find out if the system has a default mail client. It can be anything , Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo mail, ThunderBird, etc.

Thanks

Deb

Comment: I think this might [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393488/check-default-mail-client-using-c-sharp-code)

Comment: the other reason it probably isn't working it because there is a space after mailto:.  There should be an e-mail address. Trying to start a process with an invalid string is probably not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and I got this error because that Outlook 2010 were installed but never configured to solve this problem you will when the system reports Outlook 2010 (and perhaps other versions as well) find a way to test if the client is configured. [This might be a good start](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/detect-whether-outlook-configured-machine-using-regis-t3719105.html)

//KH.

Comment: That might be the case but what end user will complain most of the time is why outlook is throwing this kind of exception. So I need to know how to handle them?

Comment: Since you are using process that error will appear in the Process.StandardError property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror